# Complexity of a random sorting

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Okay this might be the worst way way to sort an array `arr` of `n` distinct integers but I want to analyse this algorithm:

1. Check if `arr` is sorted. If so, return.
2. Randomly permute the elements of `arr`.
3. Repeat Steps 1 and 2 until there is a `return`.

Will Goofy’s sorting procedure work at all? What is a best case for GoofySort? What is the running time in the best case? What is the worst-case running time? What is the average case running time?

Comment: And what have you reasoned so far (remember to show your work...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the [bogosort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) algorithm..

To answer your questions:

> What is a best case for GoofySort?

In the best case, the array is already sorted, or the first randomisation sorts it.

> What is the running time in the best case?

Either the time it takes to check it's sorted, or the time it takes to shuffle, and checking twice for sorting.

> What is the worst-case running time?

It's infinite. You could shuffle {1,3,2} => {3,1,2} => {1,3,2} => {3,1,2} forever.

> What is the average case running time?

It's O((n+1)!) (see the wiki article).

Comment: The first CS paper referenced by Wikipedia actually itself references Walt Disney's Mary Poppins. XD

Answer (score 3):

This sort is called [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

- Best case is `O(n)`: your first shuffle returned a sorted list. If this happens for any decently sized list, you should probably buy a lottery ticket.
- Average case is `O((n+1)!)`
- Worst case is unbounded. There's no guarantee that the random shuffling will ever return a sorted list. It is random after all.